# What is “Magen Darm”?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, noun

I just saw a friend write this in Whatsapp:

> Ich hab mal wieder Magen Darm

I guess she is trying to say that her tummy hurts, but I do not get why she wrote it like this. *Magen* is *stomach* and *Darm* is *intestine*. Both together do not make much sense, do they?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Magen Darm" is wrong, it needs an hyphen: "Magen-Darm".

That is short and colloquial for all kind of deseases that affect stomach and intestine at the same time (=diarrhea with vomiting/sickness).

The according long names would be [Magen-Darm-Entzündung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastroenteritis), Magen-Darm-Infektion, Magen-Darm-Grippe or Brechdurchfall.

---

Comment: Why do I think "Magen-Darm" is better than "Magendarm"?

Duden defines [Brechdurchfall](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Brechdurchfall) as "eine mit Erbrechen und Durchfall einhergehende Erkrankung des **Magen-Darm**-Kanals"

Comment: Magen-Darm ist richtig, auch wenn man bedenkt, dass es im menschlichen Körper kein "Magendarm" gibt, nur Magen UND Darm. Dasselbe gilt beispielweise Hals-Nasen-Ohren- und Herz-Lungen-Krankheiten.  Im "Arztlateinischen" setzt man die Wörter jedoch ohne Bindestrich zusammen, z.B "Laryngotracheitis" "Rhinosinuitis" "Gastroenteritis" etc

Comment: Ich verstehe und akzeptiere, dass ihr "Magen-Darm" mit Bindestrich schreibt. Dann fällt mir aber gleich was auf: Rätselhaft ist mir, dass im Folgesatz "Brechdurchfall" zusammen geschrieben wird (Ich weiss natürlich, dass das so "richtig" ist, nach derselben Logik müsste man es aber auch mit Bindestrich schreiben)

Answer (score 4):

As I recently outlined in my answer to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/33407), writing <del>*Magen Darm*</del> is wrong according to the German spelling rules. It should be *Magendarm.*

*Magendarmgrippe* is a colloquial term for what doctors would call [*Gastroenteritis*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastroenteritis) — an umbrella term for a number of infections that cause vomiting and/or diarrhoea. It has nothing to do with influenza, even though the same root *Grippe* is used. Colloquially, it is common to drop *Grippe* and just speak of *Magendarm.*

While I myself am not trained in medicine and thus don’t know what a doctor would actually call *Gastroenteritis,* I would assume that colloquial usage of *Magendarm(grippe)* is broader than the original term. It is typically already used for severe unwellness that one attributes to the intestinal tract; whether an infection is the cause or not.

So what your friend wanted to say is that she is unwell, probably vomiting or suffering from diarrhoea.

Comment: I get what she wanted to tell. I was just curious at 2 things: 1) The words were separate 2) Grippe was nowhere to be found

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent 1) Many peolpe unfortunately make that spelling mistake 2) I added a sentence. I glossed over the issue of the missing grippe. It is now explicit.

Comment: *Magendarmgrippe* is not correct in my opinion. Instead I'd say it must be *Magen-Darm-Grippe*, as the term is not really a composite noun, but a contraction of *Magen- und Darm-Grippe*. *Magendarmgrippe* wäre eine Erkrankung des "Magendarms" (whatever that's supposed to be).

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar To me, the word has become one. I wouldn’t have known that people consider it a contraction of *Magengrippe und Darmgrippe* or *Magen- und Darm-Grippe* although it doesn’t seem illogical per se. I don’t consider the individual constituents of the word to retain any meaning of their own, and the way I pronounce it doesn’t suggest that they should be separated. Thus, I’m sticking with the non-hyphenated variant.

Comment: @Jan Für mein Sprachgefühl ist *Magendarmgrippe* ein Wort. Der Duden würde es wahrscheinlich, wie *Magen-Darm-Katarrh*, als Aneinanderreihung einstufen und mit Bindestrichen schreiben. http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/bindestrich#K26